# No puedo usar la función getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color de un encabezado cuando pase el mouse encima de el y cuando salga, pero cuando quiero acceder al nodo mediante la función `getElementById()` el navegador devuelve el error:

> `document.getElementbyId(...) is null`

No se donde puede estar el problema. Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
function resalta(elemento) {
    switch(elemento.style.backgroundColor){
        case 'green':
            elemento.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        break;
        case 'red':
            elemento.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        break;
        default:
            elemento.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}

document.getElementById("ensayo1").onmouseover = resalta;
document.getElementById("ensayo1").onmouseout = resalta;
```

Answer (score 2):

Eso te ocurre porque tienes mal implementada la función, el parámetro `elemento` no hace referencia al elemento HTML, sino al parámetro `this`, para acceder al elemento HTML se usa `currentTarget`

```js
function resalta(elemento) {
    switch(elemento.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor){
        case 'green':
            elemento.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        break;
        case 'red':
            elemento.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        break;
        default:
            elemento.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}

document.getElementById("ensayo1").onmouseover = resalta;
document.getElementById("ensayo1").onmouseout = resalta;
```

```html
<div id="ensayo1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quia itaque quo? Reiciendis laborum voluptatem aliquid harum magni voluptatibus minus vel quidem numquam ipsam molestiae omnis temporibus, recusandae in doloremque.</div>
```

Comment: No digo que tu respuesta no sea buena, al contrario, solo creo que hubiese sido bueno esperar a que el OP publicará su HTML. Saludos.